# Word for act of pulling hair back using scalp muscles

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What do you call the act of pulling your hair back using your scalp muscles?

For instance, watch [Nathan Fillion's scalp](https://youtu.be/Of9kHpCv1ts?t=26m45s) in this cut from Dr. Horrible's Sing Along Blog. Or, here's a less known but [more obvious](https://youtu.be/RspOitNd_1o?t=30) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a single word for that. It's called **flexing your scalp muscles**, or **contracting your scalp muscles**, or simply **moving your scalp**:

> It's interesting no one has mentioned this one yet: I can **move my scalp**. I can move my scalp forward and backwards without moving my ears or eyebrows.

([www.neatorama.com](http://www.neatorama.com/2008/03/12/things-that-are-almost-impossible-to-do-with-your-body/))

Comment: Or **tensing your scalp muscles**. But yes, doesn't seem to be anything nicer.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this link will be helpful for you.

http://www.shapeyourface.com/exercise_five.htm

Comment: Yes, but what do you call it? "Hey, in that Dr. Horrible clip, you can really see Nathon Fillion <verb>ing!"; what's "<verb>"?

Comment: I call it flexing those frontalis and occipitalis muscles causing scalp movement.